# Looking for relative contribution of log and standard variables

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am looking to measure the contribution of variables in an OLS model. I have been using the "relimp" package to measure it. However, some of the variables in the model are logged, while some are not. Does anyone have information on how to specify which variables are logged to get the exact contribution of the variable? In this package or another?

I am trying to see the actual and predicted sales based on the decomp of each variable

Log(sales)= B0 + B1*Log(Spend) + B2*GRP + B3 * Distribution  +....

Comment: OLS makes no assumptions about the scale or metric of the inputs. In terms of 'actual' vs 'predicted' you would need to retransform the predicted log of sales back into its original units with an *exp()* function. 'Contribution of variables' can imply different terms with different interpretations. One term is 'relative importance of variables.' The best review of this issue is Ulrike Groemping's papers and R module RELAIMPO (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v017i01/v17i01.pdf). The second term is 'effect size' which is typically considered at a higher level than the unique variable

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I ended up doing manually eventually with exp but I was hoping to find a package where this could be done. I looked up RELAIMPO too. Thank you for trying D.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the relative contribution of variables, you should analyze structure coefficients. In R you can use the `yhat` package. The structure coefficients will not change with the transformations. Additionally, I'm not sure why you need to log transform an independent variable. This might needlessly complicate your analysis